# ng-repeat template compilation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a template variable in my HTMl that I want to compile ,
the thing is this variable value looks like this :

```
item.template = "{{ 'some string' + data | translate }}";
```

so what I have is this template that needs data compilation in it . this template is within **ng-repeat** , so what I need a way to compile this template within my html **without creating an isolated custom directive** ,

I tried to do the following :

```
<div ng-init="x={{item.template}}"></div>
{{x}}
```

but this is causing an error .

> [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 4 of the
>   expression [x={{column.template}}] starting at [{column.template}}].

Is there a simple way to solve it without isolated scopes ?

Comment: You shouldn't have template snippets in your model. Templates should be in the HTML only. Pass the data to the template instead of passing the snippet, or use the $translate service in the JS code and pass the result to the template. Maybe you could explain what you're trying to achieve, at a higher level.

Comment: that's not the correct way to use the translate filter from inside your javascript, and won't work.  Also, that's not the appropriate use for `ng-init`.

Comment: can you re-word your question to show what you are actually trying to accomplish?  as it stands now, we don't have a lot of context, and this looks more like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Claies sure , I have a table directive . that has a template per cell , to solve my current issue I have to create a custom directive that does the following : $compile(element.contents())(scope); in isolated scope per each because I am in ng-repeat . How can I avoid that ?

Comment: that doesn't clarify the problem at all.  `ng-repeat` by itself would never require you to use `$compile`.  You didn't describe  the higher level concept of what you are trying to accomplish; you described another possible attempt at a still unknown problem that doesn't do what you want.  try creating a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: I *feel like* what you are trying to do here is make some sort of directive that can be used inside an `ng-repeat` and will translate the data on that line, is that what the goal is here?